# ¿Como obtener la actual URL de una pagina con PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo un problema cuando pongo el `´´$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI];´´` No me muestra la **url** completa de la pagina solo parte de ella, no se si es falla en el codigo porque en otros lugares si me funciona o tiene que ver con la ubicacion del formulario que lo solicita.

Podrian ayudarme.

Comment: podrias dar un ejemplo de lo que esperas y lo que te muestra?

Comment: Necesiro que me regrese la URL del sitio eso es todo pero me regresa unicamente el host
Es decir si quiero google.com/Anime.html
solo me sale Google.com

Answer (score 1):

```
$host= $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; //Optiene el host ej http://miweb.com
$url= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; // Optiene la url de la pagina actual ej */home
echo "http://" . $host . $url; //y aqui regresa http://miweb.com/home
```

Comment: tener en cuenta que la diferencia entre http y https puede venir por `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` o `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']` en caso de proxies o balanceadores de carga

Answer (score 0):

Intenta así:

```
 "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}. 
{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"
```